# UpnEndpointIdentity not supported in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to "rewrite" a Windows 8.1 (WinRT) application and utilize the new Windows 10 framework.

The application uses internal company WCF. The generated code includes the following line (which is part of the service client constructor):

```
return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new System.Uri("net.tcp://internalCompanyService/Service"), new System.ServiceModel.UpnEndpointIdentity("identity@company.ad"));
```

Unfortunately, when that is executed the following exception is thrown:

> An exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: UpnEndpointIdentity is not supported

This is quite an issue. I'm using a WCF service - the configuration for said service might be a bit more complex than usual, but it works in WinRT.

Is there a trick I'm missing to get this to work in Windows 10?

Comment: It seems there's an open ticket on that. See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/10)

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks. Still, if anyone knows of a workaround, that'd be fantastic.